# how to configure AWS elastic beanstalk to terminate at SSL without a custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I'm migrating parse server to AWS following the migration guide. All seem to work except I can't figure out how to turn on SSL for the AWS elastic beanstalk environment running parse server.

I've used the AWS certification manager to create a ssl certification and add that to the load balancer for the elastic beanstalk using [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html). But in the case of parse server, I don't have a external url/domain. The mobile app would use the ***.elasticbeanstalk.com domain directly.

I tried to select the existing ***.elasticbeanstalk.com SSL certificate ID for the load balancer but it doesn't seem to work. I got error saying `Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-t-AWSEBLoa-18JCU6CAOVHW5 failed Reason: Server Certificate not found for the key: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:741843978711:certificate/dff6a710-2111-4ab7-99eb-8aaaf0bc7510`

Any idea how I can enable SSL using the ***.elasticbeanstalk.com domain name?

Comment: You can't create an SSL certificate for a domain name you don't own. It doesn't seem like a good idea to have your app use the *.elasticbeanstalk.com domain directly.

Comment: @MarkB i c. thanks for clarification. i thought since the backend url are not directly visible to app users, it wouldn't matter much whether I use a custom domain name or the vanilla elasticbeanstalk.com domain.